# Does Spec functor sends pushouts of rings into pullbacks of sets?

Tags: ct.category-theory, ring-spectra, pullback

*This question was posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3333736) on StackExchange.*

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $B,C$ be two commutative $A$-algebras.
Consider the pushout square of ring homomorphism
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
A@>\beta>>B\\
@V\gamma VV@VVV\\
C@>>>B\otimes_AC
\end{CD}
In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3215844) answer it is proved that the corresponding commutative square of spectrum $\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$
\begin{CD}\tag 1
\Spec(B\otimes_AC)@>>>\Spec(B)\\
@VVV@VV\Spec(\beta)V\\
\Spec(C)@>>\Spec(\gamma)>\Spec(A)
\end{CD}
is a pullback in the category of schemes.

I'm looking for sufficient conditions on $A\to C$ which make $(1)$ a pullback square in category of sets for every $A\to B$.

Two such conditions are:

- if $C=A/\mathfrak a$ for some ideal $\mathfrak a$ of $A$;
- if $C=S^{-1}A$ for some mutliplicative system $S$ of $A$.

Note that in both case, $A\to C$ is an epimorphism of commutative rings; so my question is:

> If $A\to C$ is an epimorphism of commutative rings, then $(1)$ is a pullback of sets for every ring homomorphisms $A\to B$?

**My try.**
Let $\beta:A\to B$, $\gamma:A\to C$ and $\tau:A\to B\otimes_AC$ and consider the pushout square of commutative rings above.
If $\gamma:A\to C$ is a ring epimorphism, then the right-handed $B\to B\otimes_AC$ is a ring epimorphism as well.
Moreover, it's know that the functions $\Spec(B\otimes_AC)\to\Spec(B)$ and $\Spec(C)\to\Spec(A)$ are injective.
By [Atiyah & MacDonald - ex. 25 pag. 48] we have
$$\operatorname{Im}\Spec(\tau)=\operatorname{Im}\Spec(\beta)\cap\operatorname{Im}\Spec(\gamma)$$
[image]

This proves that for every set $X$ there exists a function $h:X\to\Spec(B\otimes_AC)$ and the injectivity of $\Spec(C)\to\Spec(A)$ implies that the left-handed triangle commutes.
*I've troubles in showing that the upper triangle commutes as well.*

Comment: Your question is unclear: first you seem to ask the general question (viz.: is it *always* true that Spec sends tensor products to pullbacks of topological spaces?), to which the answer is a resounding “NO” ($\mathbb{A}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$ as a topological space is not the product of two copies of $\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$), then you ask about a specific equivalence: so, which is your question?

Comment: If the second question is your real question, you can't seriously hope to do a characterization with $A\to C$ only, since the situation is symmetric and $A\to B$ plays exactly the same rôle! If $A\to B$ satisfies one of the sufficient conditions you listed and $A\to C$ does *not*, then the diagram will still be a pullback of topological spaces!

Comment: So maybe your real question should be: under what conditions on $A\to C$ is it true that Spec takes $B\otimes_A C$ to the fiber product of topological spaces for **all** $A\to B$. But whatever the case, you should clarify your question because, so far, it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: What is $X$ in your diagram?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Here $X$ is a generic set (or topological space); I'm trying to prove that the square of spectrum has the universal property of a pullback square in the category of sets (or topological spaces).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me work directly with schemes (you can of course restrict to affine schemes if necessary).

For $S$-schemes $X,Y$ there is a natural map
$$|X \times_S Y| \to |X| \times_{|S|} |Y|,$$
which is surjective, and the fiber of $(x,y,s)$ can be identified with
$$\mathrm{Spec}(k(x) \otimes_{k(s)} k(y)\bigr).$$
So the condition is equivalent to saying that these tensor products have exactly one prime ideal.

If $X \to S$ is a monomorphism of schemes, then $k(s) \to k(x)$ is an epimorphism between fields, hence an isomorphism. Hence, $ k(x) \otimes_{k(s)} k(y) \cong k(y)$, and the result follows.